# Array of Cells to store cells, without warning

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, cell-array

I'm reading in a file(line by line), and returning it as a <1x175 cell>. It's a big file with big computations so I split it into pieces. I understand preallocating will speed up my code, so I made an array to store my data from the file.

```
warning('off','MATLAB:NonScalarInput');
dataInput = cell(NumOfPartitions,(1:175));
```

I've made this work in the past without the *Warning: Input arguments must be scalar.* but I've forgoten how I did it... This seems to work but I feel like it may not be wise. Here's what it looks like;

```
dataInput <8,1 cell> =
<1x175 cell>   *<1x175 cell>*  ... <1x175 cell>
```

So if i dataInput(2) it will return the second **<1x175 cell>**

Comment: Can you add example input data (MATLAB code that generates a small example input cell array) and desired output for that example input? It seems to me that you want to have cell arrays inside your output cell array, or that you have cell arrays inside your input cell array, but it's hard to say how to convert to another data structure without example input and output.

Comment: reads a line, then using a delimiter, cuts into 175 pieces to sotre as cells. Each cell has different data, and are _mostly_ converted within (to their double, string, etc). [5678] [0] [0] [Baka_Riley] ... [9.999999] It's strange because i need to allocate a cell (not an array ><) of size _NumOfpartition_ while also making each cell within have a size of 1x150. I think the way i did it works fine, but the warning scares me a bit. either way thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
dataInput = cell([NumOfPartitions 175]);
```

This will make an 8x175 cell arrangement. I think that should still be able to contain all of your data... I'm a bit confused though, because you have a reference to both 125 and 175 in your question.

The reason you're getting a warning is that you're trying to pass an array (`1:125`) to the `cell` function. You're effectively asking MATLAB to create a cell array of size (8, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 125). Which MATLAB guessing is not what you're trying to do. And it's right about that!

Comment: i see what i'm doing wrong! Thanks!! I didnt understand what that was doing before, and I didnt make the connection till now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To preallocate a cell array you can use this:

You can do it this way:

```
CellArray = cell(Height, Width);
```